# Java Swing adding images code in MigLayout does not seem to be working?

Tags: java, image, swing, javax.imageio, miglayout

So I have my own custom `JFrame`, and in it I am trying to create an auto-resizing image to be contained in my `JFrame`'s content `JPanel`, `frameContent`. My layout manager for the `JPanel` is `MigLayout`, so I figured I would create a child of `JPanel` again, called `ImagePanel`. Here is what my `ImagePanel class` ended up looking like:

```
class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5602032021645365870L;
    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        try {                
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("../res/Title.png").toURI()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);      
    }

}
```

Now for some reason it doesn't seem like it's actually 'working'. When I am setting up my main `JFrame`'s content, I call:

```
framecontent.add(new ImagePanel(),  "pos 5% 5% 95% 45%");
```

It's not that it's not adding the component, as with this code I'm able to get the following screen:

[image]

Notice how it outlines the area against the gray background, meaning the `paintComponent(g)` method is being run, and the program also isn't outputting any errors, which is strange, so that means it is finding my image, just not placing it.

Here is what my file hierarchy looks like:

```
Project Folder >
    src >
        res >
            Title.png (Picture I want to retrieve)
        guiwork >
            Working.class (Class that is running instructions/ main)
```

Got it all fixed up, here is the auto-resizing result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Notice how it outlines the area against the gray background, meaning the paintComponent(g) method is being run, and the program also isn't outputting any errors, which is strange, so that means it is finding my image, just not placing it.

Not so as a null image will throw no errors. To prove this, test your image variable in the paintComponent method and you'll likely find that it is in fact null.

i.e., try this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("image is null: " + (image == null)); // TODO: Delete this
    g.drawImage(image, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);      
}
```

Solution: don't change your resource to a file, but instead use the resource as is, and make sure that you're looking for it in the correct location.

---

**Edit**
Oh **chit**, you're drawing your image beyond the bounds of your component:

```
g.drawImage(image, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
```

try:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
```

---

**Edit 2**
What if you try a simple test program, something like:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestImage {
   public TestImage() throws IOException {
      String path = "/res/Title.png";
      BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         new TestImage();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

and be sure to place this in the same location as your current class. Does it run?

Comment: I already tested it with `if(image == null)System.out.println("Image is null");`, and it did NOT output `'Image is null'`...

Comment: @tanishalfelven: hm, what did it output?

Comment: @tanishalfelven: please see my edit, the one that begins, "oh chit".

Comment: It didn't have any output besides the Frame, and it didn't change **at all** when I used `0, 0`, Thanks for trying though :D.

Comment: Could it be related to the way I set the file path? Now that I look at it, it seems a little sketchy...

Comment: @tanishalfelven: you shouldn't be using files here at all. As I have mentioned stick with resources. Class's `getResource()` returns a URL and `ImageIO.read(...)` **accepts** a URL parameter. Use that.

Comment: @tanishalfelven: and regarding path, you might want to post an image of your path relative to the class files.

Comment: Ok, so I am using `image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../res/Title.png"));` to get the image, and `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` to draw it, but it is still giving me the blank screen...

Comment: @tanishalfelven: see comment above your last one. If you're using Eclipse, please show an image of your package explorer showing us where your image is relative to your class files/project.

Comment: I made a diagram, it displays what you need to know (in my question)

Comment: @tanishalfelven: get rid of your two dots, `..`. Try, `image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/res/Title.png"));`

Comment: I thought I needed them to go up a directory, because in `getClass().getResource()` it starts in the directory of the `.class` that is calling the instructions? I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: I just tested that in the same directory, and my `image` appeared, and it ran fine. How could I apply that to my current code?

Comment: @tanishalfelven: You've gotten rid of the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` bits, right? Have you put a border around your ImagePanel object to debut that it is where you think it is?

Comment: Yes. It is drawing the image, but I think that it is too large to display in my small area. So basically, for some reason it is not resizing the image with my calls.

Comment: I just tested to see if it was not resizing the image by making the Panels bounds 100% of the screen, and it is **NOT** resizing the image . Do you know how to fix this? To clarify, it is finding the image, just no resizing.

Comment: @tanishalfelven: yes, use a different `g.drawImage(...)` overload. The one that actually resizes the image. Please check the Graphics API for the correct method.

Comment: Yeah I'll post a picture on my answer. It's for a game I'm creating, because to learn how to use Java GUI better, which I've never been to good at.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have trouble understanding HoverCraft's Answer:

Say you have a Panel in which you want to add an image that scales, the following code does that for you

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MasterSlidePanel extends JPanel {
    private ImageIcon imageIcon;
    private JLabel image;

    public MasterSlidePanel() {
        super(new MigLayout("", "2% [] 2%", "2% [] 2%"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public void setImage(SlidePanel panel) {
        imageIcon = <Where you get the imageIcon>;
        image = new JLabel();
        image.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        image.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        this.add(image, "width 96%, height 96%");
    }
}
```

We add 2 new members to the panel, image and imageIcon. The moment when the application needs to paint the panel, a scaled inscance of the imageIcon is loaded and given to image.

To prevent 0 height/width errors, we add a minimumsize to the JLabel.

Hope this helps.

Credits still go to HoverCraft Full Of Eels.